# i cannot understand the code e1.sal <= e2.sal

Tags: sql, plsql, correlated-subquery

```
select distinct salary 
from downtodate1.employe AS e1 
where 3 = (
    select count(distinct salary) 
    from downtodate1.employe e2 
    where **e1.salary <= e2.salary**
);
```

Please explain the line

```
e1.salary <= e2.salary
```

Comment: What don't you understand about that line? Please be more specific with your questions.

Comment: `<=` is "less than or equal to" if that is what you are asking. However I have no idea what specific part of that expression you do not understand so please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just comparing the salary column in both tables to each other, if the one in the first table is less than or equal to the one in the second table it will be a result in the inner select statement.